# How does one merge and compute array items within a nested array structure via a fixed condition/rule

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, merge, reduce

I have an JavaScript heterogenous array of arrays which looks like :

`let bigArray = [["A", "B", 221.67],["C", "B", 221.65],["B", "D", 183.33],["B", "A", 4900],["E", "B", 150],["A", "B", 150]]` 
Now i want to add the 3rd element(number) if the first and second elements matches with the first and second element of next array(in multidimensional array), then add 3rd element(number) of both array & also perform minus operation if reverse of those elements match is found.

Output will be:

`let ans = [["B", "A", 4528.33],["C", "B", 221.65],["B", "D", 183.33],["E", "B", 150]]`

sub array ["B","A", 4528.33] is formed by performing minus operation, i,e 4900-221.67-150

In bigArray there are array with repeated pair of elements like "A" & "B"(in single sub array). So for all matching subarrays perform sum operation & if reverse of that matching sub array is found then perform minus operation. i,e=> 4900-221.67-150

I tried many methods but cant able to achieve the desired output for all the cases. Any help will be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: SO is not a free code service. Please at least include an attempt you made to solve this.

Comment: what qualifies if adding or subtracting a value? the order of the first two values?

Comment: @NinaScholz I am trying to mimic splitwise / kitty split, so for more transaction between 2 users i want to add their amount & perform minus operation if reverse of match is found

Comment: @Shivashankar What was Nina trying to say is, "AB" and "BA" --> "AB" is found in array first, so with your explanation "BA" would be the minus operation, what would lead to 221.67-4900 and after all a negative result. But your output desires 4528.33 to be positive. What qualifies 4528.33 to be positive here and not -4528.33

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm suppose consider if any combination say if "BA" results in negative, then we need to change the order(reverse) & store it as "AB" with positive result. It means for each negative value we encounter while performing this operation we need to reverse the order & store the amount(number) as positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could group with sorted keys to maintain a standard key and check if the part keys have the same order, then add the value or subtract.

If a value is negative change the keys and take a positive value.

```js
let data = [["A", "B", 221.67], ["C", "B", 221.65], ["B", "D", 183.33], ["B", "A", 4900], ["E", "B", 150], ["A", "B", 150]],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, [a, b, v]) => {
        const key = [a, b].sort().join('|');
        if (r[key]) {
            r[key][2] += a === r[key][0] ? v : -v;
            if (r[key][2] < 0) r[key] = [r[key][1], r[key][0], -r[key][2]];
        } else {
            r[key] = [a, b, v];
        }
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```